# Abort insertion if duplicate

Tags: mysql, pdo

I want to insert 5 new lines in a table if and only if none of the 5 lines are already there. If one of them is in the table, then I want to abort the insertion (without updating anything), and know which one (or which ones) were already there.

I can think of long ways to do this (such as looking if `SELECT col1 WHERE col1 IN (value1,value2,...)` returns anything, and then inserting only if it doesn't)

I also guess transactions can do this, but I'm currently learning how they work. However, I don't know if a transaction can give me which entry(ies) is (are) a duplicate(s).

With or without transactions, is there any way to do this in one or two queries only ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a better way than the solution you mentioned: First run a `SELECT` query and if it doesn't return anything, `INSERT`. You asked for something in one or two queries. This is exactly two queries, so pretty efficient in my view. I can't think of an efficient way to use transactions for this. Transactions are good when you have multiple `INSERT` or `UPDATE` queries, you have only one.

Answer (score 0):

The insert instruction does not give a lot of chances to do the job. If you turn on an UNIQUE constraint in the desired field and than insert all the fields in only one instruction such

```
  INSERT INTO FOO(col1) VALUES
  (val1), 
  (val2),
  (val3),
  (val4),
  (val5);
```

It is going to give an exception due the constraint violation and therefore abort the instruction.
If you want avoid the exception the job becomes a little pervert:

```
  INSERT INTO FOO(col1) VALUES
  Seleect a.* from  (Select val1
        union 
  Select val2
        union
  select val3
        union
  select val4
        union
  select val5 ) a 
   inner join 
  ( select g.* from( 
        select false b from foo where col1 in(val1,val2....)
        union 
        select true) g 
    limit 1) b    on b.b
```

What happen? the most inner query returns true only if there is no values therefore it will insert all the values only if there is no values.

Comment: OP wants to know which one (or which ones) were already there, if any.